# What should I do when the python setup keeps initializing and doesn't continue?

Tags: python, installation

[first like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUsGu.jpg)
[and finished like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYdsb.jpg)
I just checked "Add Python 3.9 to PATH" and clicked "Install Now". Then the setup kept initializing for several minutes, and failed at last.

I tried to reboot my computer, but it didn't work. And I tried several python setups of different versions(not lower than v3.8), but they behaved the same.

Comment: What does it say in Chinese?

Comment: That's like a time-out error.

Comment: There isn't a lot of information here to go on, but I can tell you that setting up your Python environment can be a pain if you're just getting started. 
You can try asking chatgpt to help you. If you're just trying to run some basic scripts, you can always try Google colab

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! Actually, I've been learning python for around a year. When I was getting started, I didn't find installing python so difficult. I just checked and clicked, and the installation finished smoothly. That's why I feel it so strange now.